# The edit distance from a large complete $p$-partite graph to the Turán graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $K=K(V_1,V_2,\cdots,V_p)$ be a $p$-partite complete graph on $n$ vertices and $T_p(n)$ be the Turán graph.

Show that: if $e(K)\geq e(T_r(n))-t$ then $$\sum_{k=1}^p\left(|V_k|-\frac{n}{p}\right)^2\leq 4t.$$

Furthermore, $$|E(K)\Delta E(T_p(n))|\leq 2n\sqrt{\frac{t}{p}}.$$

This statement was claimed in [Füredi - A proof of the stability of extremal graphs, Simonovits' stability from Szemerédi's regularity](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2015.05.001) where it is stated that it can be proved by 'simple calculation'.

I have no idea towards the first inequality. For the second one, I managed to prove a weak one from the first:

$$ 4tp\geq\sum\left(|V_k|-\frac{n}{p}\right)^2\sum 1^2\geq \left(\sum \left||V_k|-\frac{n}{p}\right|\right)^2.$$

Since we need to edit at most $n$ edges for a vertex, then $|E(K)
\Delta E(T_p(n))|\leq 2n\sqrt{tp}$.

Any idea is welcomed!

Remark: differed by a constant is not important. So we no longer need to juggle with the ceil or floor function in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first inequality:
\begin{align*}
\sum(|V_i| -\frac{n}{p})^2 &= \sum\left(|V_i|^2 - 2\frac np |V_i| + \frac{n^2}{p^2}\right) \\
&= \left(\sum |V_i|^2\right) - 2n^2/p + n^2/p \\
&= 2\left( \sum \binom{|V_i|}{2} + \frac{|V_i|}{2}\right) - n^2/p \\
&= 2\left(\binom n2  - e(K) + \frac{n}{2}\right) - n^2/p \\
&\le 2\left(\frac{n^2}{2} - e(T_{n,p}) + 2t\right) - n^2/p \\
& = 2(\frac{n^2}{2p} + 2t) - n^2/p = 4t
\end{align*}